# What is a Context Manager as applied to computer programming and programming languages?

Tags: computer-science

Reading code bases I sometimes come across classes named as ContextManager. Programming languages, such as Python, have the idea of context manager. What exactly is context manager? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

While a program is running, certain operations are only permitted at certain times. For instace, you can only read a file when you have the file open.

Context managers keep track of this type of information and help to automatically wrap up loose ends. In Python, there is a special syntax for them that starts using with:

```
with context_manager_thingy(something) as x:
    x.dosomething
```

Leaving the with block calls the context manager's cleanup methods.